# ASP - Method only works using debugger, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, shopping-cart, httpcontext

I made a website with a shoppingcart.

I have a table with cartItems:
* [ItemId]
* [CartId]
* [Quantity]
* [DateCreated]
* [TeabagId]

### What should this method do?

This method returns an ID used to retrieve the cart of the current user (logged in, or logged out). If the user is logged in, it returns the username. If the user is logged out, it returns a random string.

The following function gets the cart ID

### Problem:

The problem is, when the debugger is not attached, it returns the username, after logging in and logging out.

### Method:

```
    public string GetCartId()
    {

        HttpContext Context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (Context.User.Identity.Name == null || Context.User.Identity.Name == "") // no user online
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[CartSessionKey] == null || HttpContext.Current.Session[CartSessionKey] == "")
            {
                Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
                HttpContext.Current.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId.ToString();
                return tempCartId.ToString();
            }
            else // sessie has cartId
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[CartSessionKey].ToString();
            }
        }
        else // User is online
        {
            return Membership.GetUser().UserName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of checking strings for null & empty yourself use, string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Comment: How are you logging the user out?

Comment: It did work, cache and filezilla were the problem.